# Access operation must use an updateable query

Tags: sql, sql-update, ms-access-2013

I have been racking my brain trying to get this to work all day, and it's almost there but I get the dreaded "Operation must use an updateable query". After multiple changes and rewrites I have ended up with the following:

```
UPDATE
    Users AS U
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
        UP.[Agent ID] AS AgentID,
        UP.[Last Name] AS LastName,
        UP.[First Name] AS FirstName,
        UP.[Team ID] AS TeamID,
        UP.[Security Profile ID] AS SecProfID,
        E.EmailID,
        UP.[Username] AS [Username],
        IIF(UP.Status = 'Active', 1,0) AS [Status],
        L.LocationID,
        Nz(DD.DateID, 1) AS HireDate,
        IIF(UP.[Rehire Status] = 'Eligible', 1, 0) AS RehireEligible,
        (SELECT 
             D.DateID 
         FROM 
             DateCodes AS D 
         WHERE
             D.DateValue = Format(Now(), "Short Date")) AS ModifiedDate
    FROM
        ((UsersPaste AS UP 
        LEFT JOIN
          DateCodes AS DD
        ON UP.[Hire Date] = DD.DateValue)
       INNER JOIN
         EmailAddresses AS E
       ON UP.[Email Address] = E.EmailAddress)
      INNER JOIN
         (SELECT 
              L.LocationID, T.TimeZone, L.Country, L.State, L.City 
          FROM 
              Locations AS L 
            INNER JOIN 
              TimeZones AS T 
            ON L.TimeZoneID = T.TimeZoneID) AS LL
      ON UP.[Time Zone] = LL.TimeZone 
        AND UP.Country = LL.Country 
        AND UP.State = LL.State 
        AND UP.City = LL.City) AS UU
  ON U.AgentID = UU.AgentID 
SET
    U.LastName = UU.LastName,
    U.FirstName = UU.FirstName,
    U.TeamID = UU.TeamID,
    U.SecProfID = UU.SecProfID,
    U.EmailID = UU.EmailID,
    U.[Username] = UU.[Username],
    U.[Status] = UU.[Status],
    U.LocationID = UU.LocationID,
    U.HireDate = UU.HireDate,
    U.RehireEligible = UU.RehireEligible,
    U.ModifiedDate = UU.ModifiedDate
```

Now, the inner Select query forming `UU` outputs exactly how the `Users` table is set up. In my mind, and correct me if I'm wrong, this should work exactly the same as if I was joining directly to another table.

Do I need to create an actual table, and insert the records formed by `UU` into that table, then update based off the new table? If I have to, I will, but I would prefer not to do that. Anyone know of any other way or what I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, yes, I think you'll need to convert your subquery into a make-table query

```
SELECT ... INTO UU FROM ...
```

and then have your UPDATE query as

```
UPDATE Users AS U INNER JOIN UU ON ...
```

In simple cases the "updateable query" issue can be avoided by using Domain Aggregate function(s). For example the following query refuses to run ("Operation must use an updateable query.")

```
UPDATE
    Donors
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            DonorID,
            SUM(Amount) AS SumOfAmount
        FROM Donations
        GROUP BY DonorID
    ) AS totals
        ON Donors.ID = totals.DonorID
SET
    Donors.TotalAmount = totals.SumOfAmount
```

but the following query works

```
UPDATE Donors
SET Donors.TotalAmount = DSum("Amount", "Donations", "DonorID=" & ID)
```

However, your case is sufficiently complex that using a temporary table is the probably the best approach.